# Creating Multi step form in symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm building a multi step form.for that I'm dynamically modifying my form based on form_events:e.g: for creating a user object with a **nationality** field, name and address, first a page is displayed and the user chooses his nationality from a select a list then submits the form, when the page reloads a form is shown for the user to enter his other info.for that I have made a subscriber that listens to the `FORMEVENTS::PRE_SUBMIT` event.if there is no data present for the nationality present I build the **nationality** form and display it to the user, if there is data for the nationality field another form is built for the **name** and **address** to enter his other info and a hidden field that contains the data for the nationality field, and sends the data back to the server when the user submits the form.

What I'm having trouble with is this:
How to validate the form for choosing nationality? Because, when it is submitted the form will change itself to the **name** and **address** form, and the validation will be for that.

Comment: Check out this bundle https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle

Comment: Great bundle https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusFlowBundle